# Ruby on Rails Ajax Memcached, well caching itself (or so it seems)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, memcached, delayed-job

This has been driving me crazy but at least now I think I've narrowed it down to what's causing it.  I just don't know the solution for it.

I've noticed that when I do low-level writing to my cache, it doesn't always give me the fresh value.  But the thing is, if I do the reading/writing from my console, it's always correct but if I'm following a process (well, so far, I've only been following with delayed_jobs), then the console is correct but the script gives me an incorrect value. For example:

```
Rails.cache.write("mood","happy")
Rails.cache.read("mood") --> happy
Rails.cache.write("mood","excited")
Rails.cache.read("mood") --> happy
```

Now I noticed that it seems to be happening only during the script AND when I refresh with Ajax.  If I do a full page refresh and then cache, it works fine; try Ajax and cache and the script gives me a wrong value.

I'm on Windows 7 and using Memcached.
Am I missing something obvious?  Could it be a setting?
In development.rb I've set:

```
 config.cache_classes = true
 config.action_controller.perform_caching = true
```

but that didn't help.

If it's not a setting, is there a way to "clear" the cache?  (The over-right should have taken care of it).

Comment: To clear the cache you can use `Rails.cache.clear`, this will clear the complete cache. To delete a particluar key `Rails.cache.delete('mood')`

Comment: I don't want to clear the whole cache every time a process runs.  I've tried a lot of things to get this to work, including delete, I believe delete_cas, inserting nil, inserting an empty string and of course, overwriting the value.   It works in my console but not in the process.